# How many guidelines I can use in android Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am new to Android Constraint layout, Is there any limitation to use **horizontal** and **vertical** guidelines? If use more than 10+ guideline, Does it affect to performance? or Is there any possibility of rendering issue?

I want to create below layout using android constraint layout.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMiHH.jpg)

Comment: Constraints are only used on layout phases (including animations, visbility and changes), so theres no rendering issue.

Answer (score 3):

I assume there is *some* performance cost to adding each `Guideline` to a `ConstraintLayout`, but they're not drawn so I assume the cost is quite small. In general, numbers like 10 or 50 aren't going to have an effect on modern hardware.

That being said, I don't see any need for a `Guideline` at all in the screenshot you posted. Using constraints to the parent or sibling views ought to be plenty.